# Playing Videos Across Multiple Browsers/Devices In Popup?

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc, html, video

I have a landing page that has a few sections on it. Each section has a button that when clicked, I would like a video to pop-up and play in a modal-type window.

I have a few questions based on all of this so far.

1. The videos are handed to me in .m4v format, which I'm handling through html5 as:

   ```
       <video id="delivervideo" width="100%" height="100%" controls>
           <source src="@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/DeliverSection.m4v")" type="video/mp4">
           Your browser does not support the video tag.
       </video>
   ```
2. This is actually embedded in a Bootstrap Modal, and looks quite terrible on any non-PC device (appears on the top of the screen and cut-off).
3. When I start playing the video, if I skip ahead using the built-in controls, the video simply stops. I am unable to start the video again unless I refresh the page and start the video over.

So my questions are sort of broad here, but they are essentially:

1. When my graphics team is handing me videos, what format(s) should I request so the video works on iOS, Android, Chrome, and IE? Is there a couple of formats I should support? We have a lot of software to be able to change the format of the videos, just unsure on what formats to use
2. If I'd like to continue opening the video in a pop-up modal-type window, is there a better solution to this than Bootstrap? Something someone here has experience with that works nicely?
3. Has anyone else experienced issues with the built-in html5 `<video>` tag controls, where skipping ahead/rewinding causes play-back issues?

I can share the page to someone through PMs if they are willing to take a look, but really nothing out of the ordinary. Just a simple `<video>` tag supporting mp4 type, while the video is in .m4v format. It only seems to work on Chrome so far, so not very useful to mobile or tablets.

Note, I am using ASP/MVC and the website is hosted in Microsoft Windows Azure as a Website, not a VM where I have control over IIS.

Comment: can't u play in html5 ?

Comment: The snippet I have above is HTML5, isn't it? That doesn't answer the questions I specifically asked in my original post though.